# Generating correct URLs with tt_news, RealURL and RSS in TYPO3

Tags: seo, typo3

I already asked this question in a German TYPO3 community but no one had any answer for me.

I used the following two articles to get my tt_news with RealURL up and running and to later add a RSS feed for my tt_news articles:

http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/suchmaschinenfreundliche-urls-seo/4785-rss-realurl.html

I hope that even non German speakers can get the information needed. So I put everything up and running, the RSS feed is being generated but the dates in the URLs are missing in the feed.

For example I’ve got an URL like www.example.com/startseite/news/datum/2010/08/29/neue-startseite-online/ generated by RealURL. In the feed the URL for the same article looks like this: www.example.com/startseite/news/datum/neue-startseite-online/. The date is completely missing. As I still don’t understand how to build custom URLs with RealURL I really don’t know how to fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And here’s the second link:

http://www.tugle.de/know_how/typo3_tutorials/realurl_konfiguration_tt_news.html

Comment: have you tried to rebuild realurl cache? What version of typo3 and realurl are you using?
edit: typoscript of tt_news part would be nice

Comment: Must haver overseen the comment, sorry. Meanwhile I’m using CoolURL which is a lot easier to implement. But thanks anyway :-).

Answer (score 1):

sorry - obsolete for the asked circumstances

#### CONSTANTS:

```
plugin.tt_news.useHRDates = 1
```

#### SETUP:

```
plugin.tt_news {
    dontUseBackPid = 1
    useHRDatesSingle = 1
    useHRDatesSingleWithoutDay = 0
}
```

#### please kick this post - asche